# Can you limit the results from a left join based on results in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, left-join

Want to join table A to table B for specific types of rows in table B. 
If none of those types are in table B, then return the row in table A with null for columns in table B.  Do not want null row, if a row with a type also returned.

My attempt to extrapolate the approach using RANK:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     A.a_id, A.emp, B.b_id, B.id_for_c, C.type, C.rnk
 FROM A
 JOIN B on B.b_id = A.a_id
 Left JOIN ( SELECT b_id, C.type, id_for_c, C.c_id, rnk
      FROM ( SELECT B.b_id, B.id_for_c, C.type, C.c_id,
            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY B.b_id
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN C.type IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS rnk
            FROM B
            LEFT OUTER JOIN C
            ON C.c_id = B.id_for_c
            AND (C.type=1 or C.type=2)
          ) C

      ORDER BY b_id, C.type, rnk) C
on C.c_id = B.id_for_c;   


Data:

create table a (a_id number, emp number);
create table b (b_id number, id_for_c number);
create table c (c_id number, type number);

insert into a values (101, 1000);
insert into a values (102, 2000);
insert into a values (103, 3000);
insert into a values (104, 4000);

insert into b values (101, 25);
insert into b values (101, 75);
insert into b values (102, 50);
insert into b values (103, 75);
insert into b values (104, 25);
insert into b values (104, 75);

insert into c values (25, 1);
insert into c values (50, 2);
insert into c values (75, 3);
```

Comment: So now you have three tables to join together. [That query returns six rows](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2fab20/1). What result do you want to see from that data? You nested `C` isn't doing anything, the `order by` in there has no bearing on the result so not sure what you're trying to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
with sub as
 (SELECT A.id, B.type
    FROM A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN B
      ON B.id = A.id_for_b
     and (B.type = 1 or b.type = 2))
select *
  from sub
 where not exists (select 1
          from sub x
         where x.id = sub.id
           and x.type in (1, 2)
           and sub.type is null)
```

Illustration:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/174bd/1/0

(your existing query is the block in the with clause). I use an exists subquery to eliminate what you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an analytic `rank()` function to favour non-null B values of null ones:

```
SELECT id, type
FROM (
  SELECT A.id, B.type,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY A.id
      ORDER BY CASE WHEN B.type IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS rnk
  FROM A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN B
  ON B.id = A.id_for_b
  AND (B.type=1 or b.type=2)
)
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY id, type;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7d48b/2).

The inner query adds a ranking column which gives each matching result a ranking of either 1 or 2 (which [you can see here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7d48b/4). The outer query then eliminates those ranked 2; which will only be null values where a non-null value also exists.

As with Brian's answer, this only hits your real tables once.

If any A has multiple non-null values, i.e. with both types 1 and 2  (or no non-nulls, but multiple nulls) then they would all be shown; I'm not sure if either scenario is possible for you.

For your three-table variation I don't think you want to be joining to a subquery; certainly not back to the tables you've already worked from. Hopefully this gets the result you want:

```
SELECT a_id, b_id, id_for_c, type, c_id
FROM (
  SELECT A.a_id, A.emp, B.b_id, B.id_for_c, C.type, C.c_id,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY B.b_id
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN C.type IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS rnk
  FROM A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN B
  ON B.b_id = A.a_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN C
  ON C.c_id = B.id_for_c
  AND (C.type=1 or C.type=2)
)
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY a_id, b_id;

| A_ID | B_ID | ID_FOR_C |   TYPE |   C_ID |
|------|------|----------|--------|--------|
|  101 |  101 |       25 |      1 |     25 |
|  102 |  102 |       50 |      2 |     50 |
|  103 |  103 |       75 | (null) | (null) |
|  104 |  104 |       25 |      1 |     25 |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2fab20/6).

Comment: Thank you too Alex. We do have the multiple nulls scenario

Comment: Alex, In trying to implement this approach in the code all the nulls are getting ranked as 1 even when a non-null exists.

Comment: @user3807647 - [it didn't for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7d48b/5), so not sure what's different. Can you show some data, or set up a Fiddle, that shows the issue?

Comment: The ranking is in the inner query, [and looks OK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2fab20/2) to me. The issue is from how you're then joining it back to the same base tables.